# Controller to return view using variable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-views

I have this variable that should be in my url but includes the "." (dot). Sorry I am still noob in laravel.

Expected Result is localhost/myProject/public/var_name

Eror says 
 View [.sampleVariable] not found.

my line is

```
return view('/'.$create->var_name)->compact('anotherVar','anotherVar');
```

and my route is 
 `Route::get('{var_name}', 'MyController@index');`

Comment: That's not enough information to make sense of where your problem might be. What's `$create`? What's your controller action look like? Do you have views in the root of your project?

Comment: what does `$create->var_name`?

Answer (score 0):

Route is

```
Route::get('/{var_name}', 'MyController@index');
```

MyController

```
public function index($var_name)
{
    return view('template.index', ['var_name' => $var_name])->compact('anotherVar','anotherVar');

}
```

Comment: what does template.index mean there?

Comment: template.index - is template blade file - \resources\views\template\index.blade.php

Comment: @Ralph it means the file located at `resources/views/template/index.blade.php`

Comment: and the ['var_name' => $var_name] ? what does it also mean? where would my compact go?

Comment: We pass $var_name in blade. compact addad

Comment: Is `compact` even a valid instance method on a `View`? I think you mean `view('template.index', compact('...'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.
**Your controller function code like**:

```
public function index($var_name)
{
    //Initiate your variable...
    $anotherVar = '';

    //Replace 'BLADEFILENAME' to you want to execute blade file name...
    return view('BLADEFILENAME', compact('var_name','anotherVar'));
}
```

You can read more about [php compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). You can also pass variable value from controller to view by [wrapping the variable in curly braces](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)

**Your route code like**:

```
Route::get('/{var_name}', 'MyController@index');
```

Now you can use `$var_name` & `$anotherVar` into your blade file.